# Take a Unicode character from within a string and decode it

Tags: python, string, unicode

I'm currently working in Python, and I'm pulling a whole bunch a data from the net, including titles of photos.  Some of the strings I'm getting have unicode in them, and I'd like to display it as its original character.

I know that if I type, for example,

```
print u'\u00a9'
```

that is will output the right character to the terminal.

However, if I get a string such as:

```
string = 'Copyright \u00a9 David'
```

I am not sure how to pull it out.

I managed to pull out the character code with RegEx, but I don't know how to insert it back in without getting an error.

I tried:

```
char = \u00a9
string = 'Copyright' + u'char' + 'David'
```

which didn't really work.

I need a way to programatically pull out the code (which I can do with RegEx), and then re-insert into the original string with the u' in front of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the `u` is. It's a way of identifying and displaying unicode *literals* in code, and has nothing to do with converting string variables from one representation to another.

What you actually need is to decode the string using the "unicode-escape" codec:

```
>>> print string.decode('unicode-escape')
Copyright © David
```

Comment: You are a beautiful human.  This does exactly what I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason why

```
char = \u00a9
string = 'Copyright' + u'char' + 'David'
```

doesn work ;-)

```
char = u'\u00a9'
string = 'Copyright ' + char + ' David'
print string
>>> Copyright © David
```

Answer (score 1):

Store char as `char = u'\u00a9'` rather than `char = \u00a9`. Then when you are appending your string just do:

```
string = 'Copyright ' + char + ' David'
```